# How do I normalize a string using ICU4C?

Tags: c, unicode, icu, normalize

I find the ICU docs somewhat challenging.

My question is: How do I normalize a string using ICU4C?

I'm looking at unorm2_normalize, but what if the buffer isn't large enough? How would I know this before? Naturally, I want to normalize the entire string.

Thanks! :>

P.S. Here is the API doc on that function: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unorm2_8h.html#a0a596802db767da410b4b04cb75cbc53

Comment: if you're not comfortable with ICU, take a look at [libunistring](http://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/libunistring.html) which might be a better fit...

Comment: I took a look at libunistring, but seems like it hasn't been updated since 2010. I would use a lot of the features from Unicode 6. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a error code back from all these function call in the pErrorCode parameter. This is how you call such a function:

```
UErrorCode error = U_ZERO_ERROR;
unorm2_normalize( ... &error );
....
if( !U_SUCCESS( error ) )
{
    // handle error...
}
```

Here are the error codes: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/utypes_8h.html#a3343c1c8a8377277046774691c98d78c

In your case you might want to do something like this:

```
if( error == U_STRING_NOT_TERMINATED_WARNING
   || error == U_BUFFER_OVERFLOW_ERROR )
{
    // enlarge the buffer...
}
```

Comment: Hallo und guten Tag! :) Thank you for answering. It seems a waste of time to attempt to normalize something, and when it doesn't work, start again from the beginning. Does the normalizer instance keep track of where it was? How do I dispose of the normalizer instance?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, I haven't used this library much yet. I would suggest one of the following approaches: 1. If you expect your input strings to be already normalized and just want to make sure: Call it with the final destination as buffer and call it again with a larger temporary buffer if it was too small. 2. If you expect the strings will usually need normalization: Call it with a much larger temprary buffer that you may also use for other things and allocate the final destination when you know the final size after the function call and copy it there.