# Unicode normalization through ICU4C

Tags: c, unicode, icu, normalize

I want to normalize a string using the ICU C interface.

Looking at unorm2_normalize, I have some questions.

1. The UNormalizer2 instance -- how do I dispose of it after I'm done with it?
2. What if the buffer isn't large enough for decomposition or recomposition? Is the normal way to check if the error code is U_BUFFER_OVERFLOW_ERROR? Does U_STRING_NOT_TERMINATED_WARNING apply? Is the resulting string null-terminated? If an error is returned, do I reallocate memory and try again? It seems like a waste of time to start all over again.

Comment: Is this question different from your [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10447452/777186) here? At least the second part seems to have been answered there, but do tell if I am wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

1. See [unorm2_close()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unorm2_8h.html#aa8b1599dfe72053c3b1c217aba1d8aac). Note that you should not free instances acquired via unorm2_getInstance()
2. In general, most ICU APIs can be passed a NULL buffer and 0 length as input which should result in  U_BUFFER_OVERLOW_ERROR and a variable populated with the required length. If you get U_STRING_NOT_TERMINATED_WARNING it means just that: The data is populated but not terminated.